# Why is CIFalseColor recoloring more than requested?

Tags: swift, cifilter

In my `ViewController.viewWillAppear`:

> ```
> super.viewWillAppear(animated)
>
> var image = UIImage(named: "colorful")! 
> let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
> imageView.frame.origin.x = 67.0
> imageView.frame.origin.y = 324.0 - image.size.height - 20.0
> view.addSubview(imageView)
>
> var image2 = ImagePainter.paint(image: image, from: UIColor(red: 243.0/255.0, green: 209.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), to: UIColor.blue)! 
> let image2View = UIImageView(image: image2)
> image2View.frame.origin.x = 67.0
> image2View.frame.origin.y = 324.0
> view.addSubview(image2View)
> ```
>
> }

ImagePainter:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ImagePainter {

  static let context = CIContext()

  static func paint(image: UIImage?, from: UIColor, to: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    guard let image = image,
      let inputImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
        return nil
    }
    let initFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor")

    initFilter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    initFilter?.setValue(CIColor(color: from), forKey: "inputColor1")
    initFilter?.setValue(CIColor(color: to), forKey: "inputColor0")

    guard let filter = initFilter,
      let filterOutput = filter.outputImage else {
        return nil
    }
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filterOutput, from: filterOutput.extent)

    let processed = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .up);

    return processed
  }
}
```

Before/After `CIFalseColor`:

[image: Before/After CIFalseColor]

This screenshot shows the original image (with the "from" color boxed in blue), and the result of calling CIFalseColor. Nothing is colored as I expected. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: All the white has maximum luminance, therefore it is mapped to `color1` which is yellow (color `from`) in your case. The dark places have low luminance are mapped to `color0` which is blue (color `to`) in your case. Seems correct.

Comment: I thought this was a "from color -> to color" filter. I just want to change 1 color into another. Is there a better way?

Comment: `CIFilter` is a filter that *Maps luminance to a color ramp of two colors.* (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIFalseColor). To just change one color into another, you don't need `CoreImage` at all. Please search for a solution because it is not related to this question at all.

Comment: I was clearly on the wrong track here. How do I delete this question?